# What does "get children on the right path to success" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "choosing the right path for children to succeed"?

"We want our children to be successful in school and life. **Getting children on the right path to success** is where the discrepancies begin. Many believe that preschools should be teaching children to read, write and perform basic math skills. Parents want to see handouts done during the day and even ask if there is homework for the children. These things have very little meaning to children."

Source: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/want-preschoolers-to-become-successful-allow-them_us_5a157ee8e4b0f401dfa7ec2f?section=us_education

Answer (score -1):

Correct.

> “get children on the right path to success”

## =

> *“teach children how to make decisions that will lead them to a prosperous life”*